# Which one is best practice for database table having two columns...one for Item1 and second for Item2?

Tags: sql, database

Which one is best practice for database table having two columns...one for Item1 and second for Item2?

```
Table Structure

Item1 | Item2
Apple | Orange
Pen   | Paper

OR

ID | Item1 | Item2
1  | Apple | Orange 
2  | Pen   | Paper
```

In short I wish to know that is it a good practice to make a primary column/field ID for tables even if they are allowed to accept multiple same values?

Comment: Can you provide more context to this subject? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Columns named "Item1" and "Item2" are a bad idea anyway...for one, cause they're useless for actually describing something...and two, because a column with a number at the end of it generally means you're violating 1NF.

Comment: The developing developer needs to develop his question a bit further...

Answer (score 1):

You should have a primary key. My *guess* from the extremely limited info you have posted is that neither of your fields will count as a primary key. Therefore, you need an id field.

(note: You could do it without, but it's a bad idea)

Answer (score 0):

Well, having a numeric ID of the record in the table, making that ID a Primary Key for the table, is a preferred way to go:

- comparison operations on the numbers are much faster then the ones on strings (given number fits into the CPU integer or long value, check the INTEGER SQL type);
- you will have your database consistent in case you'll want to rename "Apple" to an "apple" or, maybe, "APPLE" one day. Without the extra ID column, you'll have to update all the dependent tables (in case you're planning to have a Primary/Foreign keys of course).
- you will have only one column in your Primary Key even for cases when you'll have both, Orange and Green apples, without the extra ID you'd have to make Primary as (Item1, Item2).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might need more than one table, but it really depends on what you need to  store and why.  Try designing your model first, then create a data structure that supports your model.

To answer your question, it looks like the second table structure is the "best practice" (or should I say 'better practice') as it contains an ID column that can act as the primary key for indexing, but it really depends on usage.  Considering the following:

One possible data structure (separates by type)

```
table - Fruit
=============
FruitId int not null identity(1,1) primary key
Name varchar(100) not null

table - OfficeSupply
====================
OfficeSupplyId int not null identity(1,1) primary key
Name varchar(100) not null
```

Another possibility (combined with a type column)

```
table - Item
============
ItemId int not null identity(1,1) primary key
Name varchar(100) not null
Type varchar(100) not null
```